# Angular 4.x: No provider for Service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am having trouble injecting a service into another service in Angular 4.x and receive the error: `Error: No provider for SkillsService!`

I have created a [repo that reproduces this error](https://github.com/GuyHarwood/angular-service-dependencies).  You can run this locally by cloning the repo and simply running `ng test` from the repo root directory.

Steps i took...

1. Create app with `ng new`
2. Create ContactService with `ng g service contact`
3. Create SkillsService with `ng g service skills`
4. Add SkillsService to constructor of ContactService (with @Inject annotation)
5. Add both SkillsService and ContactService to app.module.ts as providers
6. Run `ng test` and receive the error: `Error: No provider for SkillsService!`

How do I add a provider to ContactService for the SkillsService?

It seems like it must be something very simple, yet it's proving hard to work out from the documentation and searching around.

Comment: Why are you doing `@Inject(SkillsService) private skillsService : SkillsService`? Can't you just use `private skillsService : SkillsService`?

Comment: @echonax this is also another way to initalize a service , i might be wrong but can you check if these services have `@Injectable()` decorator on top

Comment: @RahulSingh I know but it has absolutely no use case in this situation.

Comment: Well, just look at the code of the test: https://github.com/GuyHarwood/angular-service-dependencies/blob/master/src/app/contact.service.spec.ts#L8. You're trying to get an instance of ContactService, which needs a SkillsService, but SkillsService is not in the providers of your testing module.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your test for ContactService uses a testing module which only declares ContactService as provider. But ContactService needs a SkillsService. So SkillsService must also be part of the providers of the testing module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [ContactService, SkillsService]
});
```

You could also use the whole application module in your test:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule]
});
```

But I wouldn't recommend that because your tests will become slower and slower while the application grows.

Comment: Thanks.  I was focusing on the app module configuration rather than the test setup.  problem solved :)